# C++ image correction library

Tags: c++

My goal is to enhance my photos, doing some auto-balance, auto-tone and pretty much what Photoshop can do. I can use Photoshop’s batch processing, however this is very slow because it does not use all the cores, it processes the image one by one.

I was thinking of making my own image enhancing tool in C++, if I can find a library that has these image processing functions I want, then use it in a multithreaded way.

I have seen OpenCV, CImg, Magick++. Which library has an adequate set of such filtering? I do not need, for example, drawing functions.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends what you want to do and what OS you use. **GNU Parallel** plus **ImageMagick** is a very powerful combo.

Comment: @MarkSetchell if ImageMagick can do it, then its C++ library would help me.

Comment: You may want to search [softwarerecs.se] for image processing tools.

Answer (score 3):

Before building your own application, think about the available tools. For example, `imagemagick` is available on unix systems, and with a bit of shell magic you might be able to achieve your desired results, including running multithreading.

As for building your own application, this is definitely possible, and OpenCV is certainly capable of doing so. For example, [histogram equalization](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html) is a primitive form of auto toning. The only problem is that you will have to implement all the clever features from photoshop by hand, which might not be the best option from a time perspective (although a very good learning exercise).